# ContactTriggerHandler not triggered

Tags: apex, trigger, after-trigger

I would like to create an Trigger Handler on the contacts that every time a contact is created it will trigger this and do some manipulation on the contact.

For some reason the trigger is not triggered ... I put many system.debug to get result but nothing shows up

my code look the following:

```
Public class ContactTriggerHandler{
    public static void afterInsert(List<Contact> newContactList){
        system.debug('test');
        AccountBuckets(newContactList);
    }
    
    private static void AccountBuckets(List<Contact> newContactList){
        system.debug('test');
        list <Account> Acc = [SELECT id, name from Account where name LIKE 'B2CGeneric%' ORDER BY name];
        Id devRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Contact.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('B2C_Guest').getRecordTypeId();
        Id devRecordTypeId2 = Schema.SObjectType.Contact.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('B2C_Guest').getRecordTypeId();
        system.debug(Acc);           
        for(Contact ContactItem : newContactList){           
            if(ContactItem.RecordTypeId == devRecordTypeId || ContactItem.RecordTypeId == devRecordTypeId2){
                system.debug(ContactItem);
               }
               
           }
    }
}
```

the system.debug('test'); is not even triggered
What am I doing wrong ?

EDIT:
I managed to have the class triggered using the following trigger code:

```
trigger ContactSuperGhost on Contact (after insert) {
    if (Trigger.isInsert)
    {
        if (Trigger.isAfter){
            system.debug('Trigger');
            ContactTriggerHandler.afterInsert(Trigger.New);

        }
    }
}
```

However every Query inside it return empty. I tried Case, contact they are all in read only so with the right permission

Comment: What is in the trigger file?

Comment: What do you mean ? I might be missing something then .. this was the code in my TiggerHandler

Comment: You need to implement a trigger, not a class. To implement a class that represents a "trigger handler" is good practice,  but such a class needs still to be called from a trigger in order to execute. Get into triggers for example [here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_intro).

Comment: Understood thx you

Comment: @FelixvanHove I managed to have the trigger Triggered .. but every Query I make inside return empty data, am I missing something ?